# Spin waits, spin loop and busy spin

Tags: busy-waiting, busy-loop

Are spin waits, spin loop and busy spin a different name for the same situation?

I read different threads and they all seem related to a loop that is "busy" checking for the availability of a resource.

Answer (score 6):

**Busy Spin**

A technique which is used in a way that it loop is running until other thread have to complete his work.

**Spin Wait**

A spin wait that you have to wait until condition for thread is true.

**Spin Loop**

Spin loop is also similar to both of above busy spin and wait spin. It means that threads have to wait for other thread for completing his work.

**By the way I think these terms can also use interchangeably. Precisely these are the same terms.**

Answer (score 1):

These three terms refer to the same concept. You can read more about it in many places, including the Wikipedia page for "Busy waiting":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting